# scala regex match by hex value

Tags: regex, scala

i want to match special characters by hex value in scala

eg tab char (ctl-I) is hex 0x09, (esc) is hex 0x1b

how can i include the hex values 0x09, 0x1b in the regex pattern and match a string to it?

Comment: What *exactly* is your input? A string containing a hex value (e.g. `"0x09"`) or a string containing a literal tab character (`" "`)?

Comment: Try any of those for *tab*: [`\x09`](https://regex101.com/r/ucKqQK/1), [`\x{09}`](https://regex101.com/r/ucKqQK/2), [`\u0009`](https://regex101.com/r/ucKqQK/3) [...more info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint)

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/dcZin1zPRG2zajjnbpHu3Q/4

Comment: i am having to read files which contain a lot of non-printable bytes - i used tab in the description above to keep the question simple, but there are multiple codes which i need to match and respond to .....

thanks all for coming back on this - the \x09... notation worked

mr